# I am seeing sql queries for fetching the posts even though it is caching the data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memcached

When I make the following call in my controller's action, I can see the first time I load the page I see the output "posts hitting the db" in console output.

```
cache_key = "posts"
@posts = Rails.cache.fetch(cache_key, expires_in: 5.minutes) do
  puts "posts hitting the db"
  Post.include(:tags).where("post_status = 1").order("id desc")
end
```

If I reload the page, I don't see the "posts hitting the db" message but I can still see the queries like:

> Processing by PostsController#index as HTML   Rendering
>   posts/index.html.erb within layouts/main   Post Load (0.5ms)  SELECT 
>   "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE (post_status = 1) ORDER BY id desc    ↳
>   app/views/posts/index.html.erb:6   Label Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "tags".*
>   FROM "tags" WHERE "tags"."id" = $1  [["id", 7]]   ↳
>   app/views/posts/index.html.erb:6   Rendered posts/index.html.erb
>   within layouts/posts (31.4ms) Completed 200 OK in 87ms (Views: 62.6ms
>   | ActiveRecord: 8.2ms)

Is this because it is caching the @posts but since the @posts object wasn't actually used it didn't even make the db call?  So when the view page does the @posts.each then it hits the db?

For example, if I remove all my html in my view page then it doesn't hit the db at all.

Answer (score 5):

When you do

```
Post.include(:tags).where("post_status = 1").order("id desc")
```

You aren't actually calling the database. You are creating a ActiveRecord scope -- so that is what you are caching. If you want to cache the results of the database call, you need to do something like:

```
cache_key = "posts"
@posts = Rails.cache.fetch(cache_key, expires_in: 5.minutes) do
  puts "posts hitting the db"
  Post.include(:tags).where("post_status = 1").order("id desc").all.to_a
end
```

Instead, which makes ActiveRecord actually populate @posts with table data.

Comment: I added ```.all``` and there was no change, I can still see the queries in the console (I'm on rails 5.x)

Comment: Is it perhaps because you had a 5 minute cache on that statement so you weren't seeing your change right away because you were still pulling just the scope from the cache?

Answer (score 1):

As @bkimble said you need to add `.all` to turn your query into a database call. However, since Rails 4, `.all` is executed lazily. As I explained in this [Memcache guide for Rails](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/building-a-rails-3-application-with-memcache), you need to force its execution, e.g., by adding `.to_a` which converts the result into an array.

Your code would then look like:

```
cache_key = "posts"
@posts = Rails.cache.fetch(cache_key, expires_in: 5.minutes) do
  puts "posts hitting the db"
  Post.include(:tags).where("post_status = 1").order("id desc").all.to_a
end
```

Comment: Good call on the lazy execution. I've updated my answer accordingly